# Por que os valores booleanos são convertidos para string em camel case no C#?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, booleano

Hoje me deparei com uma peculiaridade do C# a qual nunca tinha parado para prestar atenção:

Ao converter um valor `bool` para `string`, o resultado é um texto em *camel case*:

```
string verdadeiro = true.ToString(); //Converte para True
string falso = false.ToString(); //Converte para False
```

Porém, para utilizar os valores literais na linguagem, é preciso escrevê-los em caixa baixa, escrevê-los em *camel case* causa erro de compilação:

```
bool verdadeiro = True; //Não compila
bool falso = False; //Não compila
```

Qual a razão dessa diferença?

Comment: Você não acha que só quem fez a linguagem pode responder isso?

Comment: Certamente é necessário um conhecimento bem aprofundado na linguagem...

Comment: Não é questão de conhecimento, é questão de _design_, fizeram assim e é assim. Os motivos por trás disso só quem decidiu é que pode responder.

Comment: Você cosidera uma questão irrelevante para a comunidade? Caso seja a opinião dos outros moderadores, posso retirá-la.

Comment: Eu não sou moderador e só fiz uma pergunta.

Comment: Eu sei, acho a sua pergunta relevante, por isso deixei em aberto a possibilidade de eliminar a pergunta, caso ela não agregue nenhum conhecimento relevante para a comunidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto é decisão dos criadores da linguagem e do *framework*, não tem nada específico.

O nome retornado como *string* começando em maiúscula é uma forma de uso comum, se precisa diferente é fácil manipular do jeito que deseja.

A palavra-chave em minúscula é consistente com o resto da linguagem que é tudo em minúsculo, não teria porque estes literais serem diferente disso.

Representação textual é uma coisa diferente do valor no código.

Comment: Inclusive, existem as versões camel case para as palavras reservadas de tipo primitivo, como String, Boolean, Int32, etc. Também desconheço a origem disso no C# e teria curiosidade de conhecer.

Comment: Isso é porque estes são os nomes dos tipos no .NET em geral, em C# se usa um alias. Também uma decisão de _design_, muito provavelmente é "herança" do C.

Comment: Não exatamente, existem tipos do *framework* escritos assim, as palavras reservadas são sempre em minúsculo.

Comment: Eu sempre imaginei que tinha algo a ver com herança do VB.

Comment: C# não descende do VB.